# Write VBA function to find period no. and week no. for 13 periods

Tags: excel, vba

Overview: I basically want to write a version of the MONTH function to work for a 13 period work year...

(Disclaimer: I'm new to VBA) What is the best way to reformat a date dd/mm/yyyy to be in terms of Period Number (1-13) and Week Number (1-4)? I've used the WEEKNUM function to sort of figure it out, but I can't quite seem to get it. I think the problem is that the start of the new year (Period 1, Week 1) is on 12/30/18 and in excel, it counts this date as being the 5th or even 6th week by how it's measured.

Weeks start on Sundays and every period of the year (13) has 4 weeks. So far I have tried:

- this basic portion of a self-written function to just get the week number portion to work and it just gives me #value, but no errors in msgbox (if it did work I may be able to figure out the rest):

  ```
   Function PeriodNum(serial_num As Date, number_periods As Integer, start_date As Date)

  Dim first_week As Integer
  Dim second_week As Integer
  Dim third_week As Integer
  Dim fourth_week As Integer
  Dim day As Integer

  first_week = 1
  second_week = 2
  third_week = 3
  fourth_week = 4
  day = serial_num

  If day >= start_date Or day <= start_date + 7 Then
  Selection.Value = first_week
      ElseIf day > start_date + 7 Or day <= start_date + 14 Then
          Selection.Value = second_week
      ElseIf day > start_date + 14 Or day <= start_date + 21 Then
          Selection.Value = third_week
      ElseIf day > start_date + 21 Or day <= start_date + 28 Then
          Selection.Value = fourth_week
      Else
      Selection.Value = "error"
  End If

  End Function
  ```

-I have also tried using the WEEKNUM function but I don't know how to get it to give me numbers 1-4 for each perspective period

Thanks so much for your help! Much appreciated

Comment: I believe the period can be had with `=ROUNDDOWN(WEEKNUM(A1)/4,0)+1` and the week with `=MOD(WEEKNUM(A1),4)` (assuming you date is in `A1`)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad --I think this could work except that I need the year start to begin on 12/30/18 and when I apply this formula it shows that day as being in the 14th period (which doesn't exist)--i wonder if I can find a way to make it work though, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, Functions whether built-in (i.e. SUM, COUNT) or user-defined like your PeriodNum, usually return a value to the cell they are entered in.  They don't modify workbook objects such as ranges which `Selection` is a member of.  Procedures `Sub`s modify objects but don't have return values.

As @VitezslavSimon alluded in his answer, you need to assign a value to the function name somewhere in your code - `PeriodNum = 1` or `PeriodNum ="error"`.

It's also a good idea to explicitly add a return Type to your functions.  In your case you could use `String` if you aren't doing any arithmetic calculations on the return value or `Variant` if you want to use the return in further calculations.  Your function definition would then be:

```
Function PeriodNum(serial_num As Date, number_periods As Integer, start_date As Date) As Variant
```

**Iterative approach to function errors**

I copied your code into a standard VBA module and put a break-point on line `first_week = 1` so i could step through the function after entering it in a cell.  To test it I put your `start_date` in cell C2 and `serial_num` in C3.  I called the function by entering `=PeriodNum(C3,13,$C$2)` in D3.

When stepping through your code, the line `day = serial_num` caused the function to end and return `#VALUE!` error in D3.

`#VALUE!` is the only error returned by UDFs that have error in them.  You don't get the luxury of run-time errors in UDFs so the only way to investigate is to step through the code and see where it falls over.

The date I was testing was 12/30/18 which has a Serial No of 43464.  You defined `day As Integer` which must be from -32,768 to 32,767.  So the underlying error is `Overflow` because 43464 is outside the allowable values for `Integer`.

**2nd. Iteration**

Changing `Integer` to `Long` overcomes that error but then

```
If day >= start_date Or day <= start_date + 7 Then
PeriodNum = first_week
```

Is always going to return 1 for `serial_num` >= `start_date` or `"error"` for `serial_num` < `start_date`.  The second part of your test `Or day <= start_date + 7` doesn't really matter because if it's `FALSE`, the other test is `TRUE`.  I tested this by extending dates down to C381 to take them into 2020.  So back to the drawing board!

**3rd Iteration**

Changing all the `Or` to `And` ensured the second part would be evaluated.

```
If day >= start_date And day <= start_date + 7 Then
    PeriodNum = first_week
ElseIf day > start_date + 7 And day <= start_date + 14 Then
    PeriodNum = second_week
ElseIf day > start_date + 14 And day <= start_date + 21 Then
    PeriodNum = third_week
ElseIf day > start_date + 21 And day <= start_date + 28 Then
    PeriodNum = fourth_week
Else
    PeriodNum = "error"
End If
```

Back in Excel I notice that 1/6/19 which should be the 1st day of period 2 is showing as 1.  So something is wrong with the test.  Changing `day <= start_date + 7` to `day < start_date + 7` should fix it but it returns `"error"`.  This is because the subsequent tests don't allow for `day = start_date + 7`.

**4th. iteration**

```
    If day >= start_date And day < start_date + 7 Then
    PeriodNum = first_week
ElseIf day >= start_date + 7 And day < start_date + 14 Then
    PeriodNum = second_week
ElseIf day >= start_date + 14 And day < start_date + 21 Then
    PeriodNum = third_week
ElseIf day >= start_date + 21 And day < start_date + 28 Then
    PeriodNum = fourth_week
Else
    PeriodNum = "error"
End If
```

Back to Excel and it looks good until scrolling down.  1/27/19 and everything below returns `"error"`.  `day` obviously can't be more than `start_date + 28`.

**5th. iteration**
Change `day = serial_num` to `day = (serial_num - start_date) Mod 28` and the tests to look at that number in relation to 0, 7, 14, 21 and 28.

```
day = (serial_num - start_date) Mod 28

If day >= 0 And day < 7 Then
    PeriodNum = first_week
ElseIf day >= 7 And day < 14 Then
    PeriodNum = second_week
ElseIf day >= 14 And day < 21 Then
    PeriodNum = third_week
ElseIf day >= 21 And day < 28 Then
    PeriodNum = fourth_week
Else
    PeriodNum = "error"
End If
```

Back in Excel and it all looks good.

**Final iteration - polish it**

There are still some improvements:

- `number_periods As Integer` isn't used so delete it
- the function `PeriodNum name is deceptive.  It isn't returning a period but a week in a period so`WeekInPeriod`
- It isn't good practice to use reserved words or VBA functions as variable names -  -
- `day` is a VBA function (returns the day in the month).  I changed it to `DayInPeriod28`.  Descriptive variable names are easier for the user to parse.
- I also changed `serial_num` to `MyDate`.
- Instead of nested Ifs, `Select Case` is more compact.
- Don't declare and define variable you are only going to use once.  It's a waste of space and time.

  ```
  Function WeekInPeriod(MyDate As Date, start_date As Date) As Variant
  Dim DayInPeriod28 As Long

  DayInPeriod28 = (MyDate - start_date) Mod 28

  Select Case DayInPeriod28
  Case Is < 7
      WeekInPeriod = 1
  Case Is < 14
      WeekInPeriod = 2
  Case Is < 21
      WeekInPeriod = 3
  Case Is < 28
      WeekInPeriod = 4
  Case Else
      WeekInPeriod = "error"
  End Select
  End Function
  ```

Comment: This is really helpful! Thanks for taking the time. I will definitely fix these pieces of my code

Comment: Glad it helped.  Please click the tick below the vote buttons to accept if this is the best answer.

Comment: It works! You have no idea how pleased I am. Bless you @MarkFitzgerald

Answer (score 1):

1) There is one problem according to code rules of VBA:

to each
Function PeriodNum(serial_num As Date, number_periods As Integer, start_date As Date)
definition you should also use row:

PeriodNum = ...

by this way you are returning a value from a function (similar to return x; in other languages)

2) Using a Selection object is unpredictable and can change any cell you have active in Excel at time of calling of method. If you are using method for computation you should use similar way:

```
Function weekCompute(date1)
    '...
    weekCompute = "val1"
End Function
```

With this function you can use this cell formula:
=weekCompute(A1)

Comment: You should add a return type to the Function (or it will be implicit Variant) and if you don't assing a return value it returns Empty for a Variant (or 0 for a Long, "" for a String, etc)

Comment: Function weekCompute(date1) As String ... should be now fully correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could just calculate the week:

```
LngPeriod = int((day - start_date +1)/7)
If lngPeriod >4 then
     PeriodNum = “error”
Else
    PeriodNum = lngPeriod
End if
```

Where The PeriodNum function returns a variant as suggested.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense...I'll try this to see if it works with all the qualifiers! Thanks!